# Header doesn't appear in print page when in landscape mode

Tags: html, css, printing

Seems the table header what is supposed to repeat on every page in print mode appears only on the first page if it exceeds a certain height ( i coudn't find any documentation about this).

On Chrome even if it doesn't appear starting page #2 a white space will appear. On the other browsers ( IE, Chrome ) it wont appear at all, only the body.

If I switch the page to portrait all works fine.

Any work around or some ideas about what are the limits for this ?

Thanks

```html
<html>
 <head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <style>
   @page { 
    size: landscape;
    margin: 1cm;
   }
  </style>
 </head>

 <body> 
  <table>
   <thead>
    <tr>
     <th>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
      xx<br>
     
     </th>
    </tr>
   </thead>
   <tbody>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
     <td>asdfas</td>
    </tr>

   </tbody>
  </table>

 </body>
</body>
```

Comment: @media print{@page {size: landscape}}

This might work in your css property

Comment: With landscape the <thead> doesnt appear starting page #2